# Difference between "ls -l" and "dir -l"

Tags: ls

What is the difference between `ls -l` and `dir -l`?

I always use `ls -l`, but my colleague (who is slightly colour blind) uses `dir -l`. Is this the only difference: `ls -l` has colour and `dir -l` not have colour? Or is there a benefit of using `dir` instead of `ls`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [`dir` info page](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/dir-invocation.html#dir-invocation):

> `dir` is equivalent to `ls -C -b`; that is, by default files are
>   listed in columns, sorted vertically, and special characters are
>   represented by backslash escape sequences.

`ls` doesn't have color by default but only when it is called with e.g. `--color=auto` or
the environment variable LS_COLORS is set. Usually the command `ls` is an alias/macro which calls `ls` with the `--color` option.